# Escape values in webhook's JSON payload in Automation for JIRA

Tags: json, jira, automation-for-jira

I have a webhook action configured using Code Barrel's [*Automation for JIRA*](https://docs.codebarrel.io/automation) add-on. It sends a request to an endpoint that expects a JSON payload.

Using the templating syntax, I can write a custom body like

```
{"some_key": "{{issue.summary}}"}
```

to template values into the JSON payload:

[image: Image showing the above template in the "Send webhook" form]

However, this is fragile; if any of the templated values contain a double quote or a backslash, we're likely to generate a syntactically invalid JSON payload.

Is there any way in *Automation for JIRA* to escape text for inclusion within a JSON string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a quick release that enables you to encode these values. You can find the docs at - https://docs.codebarrel.io/automation/smart-fields/working-with-strings.html#encoding

Though it is pretty simple:

```
{"some_key": "{{issue.summary.jsonEncode}}"}
```

This is live in Cloud and available in version 3.9.7 in Server.

Hope that is what you were after.